# NumPy equivalent of pandas datetime accessor operations

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

Using Pandas, I can convert a datetime series to a date series via `mySeries.dt.date`.

How would the same look like for a numpy column? Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["31.12.1999 23:59:12", "31.12.1999 23:59:13", "31.12.1999 23:59:14"], "b": [4, 5, 6]})
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df.a)
df["date"]=df.datetime.dt.date
print("df.columns:", df.columns)
df.columns: Index(['a', 'b', 'datetime', 'date'], dtype='object')
```

<!- ->

```
# convert to numpy array
dfVal = df.values
# display datetime
print("dfVal[:,2]:", dfVal[:, 2])
dfVal[:,2]: [Timestamp('1999-12-31 23:59:12') Timestamp('1999-12-31 23:59:13')
 Timestamp('1999-12-31 23:59:14')]
```

<!_- >

```
# try to convert
dfVal[:, 2].dt.date
```

<!- ->

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2963, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-12-5cead683e881>", line 1, in <module>
    dfVal[:, 2].dt.date
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'dt'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df
                     a  b            datetime
0  31.12.1999 23:59:12  4 1999-12-31 23:59:12
1  31.12.1999 23:59:13  5 1999-12-31 23:59:13
2  31.12.1999 23:59:14  6 1999-12-31 23:59:14

arr = df['datetime'].values
```

---

`dt.date`

```
arr.astype('datetime64[D]')
# array(['1999-12-31', '1999-12-31', '1999-12-31'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

---

`dt.month`

```
arr.astype('datetime64[M]') - arr.astype('datetime64[Y]') + 1
# array([12, 12, 12], dtype='timedelta64[M]')
```

---

`dt.year`

```
arr.astype('datetime64[Y]')
#  array(['1999', '1999', '1999'], dtype='datetime64[Y]')
```

---

`dt.date`

```
arr.astype('datetime64[D]') - arr.astype('datetime64[M]') + 1
# array([31, 31, 31], dtype='timedelta64[D]')
```

Comment: quite impressive! Very good! Actually I would like to get a `date` back (so a `1999-12-31` value)

Comment: @user7468395 does arr.astype('datetime64[Y]') work for you?

Comment: @Ben.T yes indeed. Thanks for spotting that. Was not at my computer so couldn't test it.